# how to handle Json body in post request in jax-rs

Tags: json, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs, restful-architecture

I have a project (homework) about JAX-RS. I'm working with NetBeans, Jersey and Tomcat.

[image]

This is my "User" class for main object in the system.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="user")
public class User {
    
    //@XmlElement
    //public int id ;
    @XmlElement
    public String username;
    @XmlElement
    public String fullname;
    @XmlElement
    public String gender;
    @XmlElement
    public String birthDate;
    
    public User(){
        
    }
    
    public User(String username,String fullname, String gender,String birthDate){
        
        //this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.fullname = fullname;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }
    
}
```

This is my "JAXBContextResolver" Class

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONConfiguration;
import com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONJAXBContext;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;


@Provider
public class JAXBContextResolver implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext>{
    
    private JAXBContext context;
    private Class[] types = {User.class};
    
    
    public JAXBContextResolver() throws Exception {
        
        this.context = 
        new JSONJAXBContext(  JSONConfiguration.mapped().build(), types); 
    }
                    
    @Override
    public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> objectType) {
         for (Class type : types) {
             if (type == objectType) {
                 return context;
             }
         }
        
        return null;
        
    }
    
}
```

And this is my post method in the "UserService" class

```
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
    public List<User> createNewUser(User tUser)  {
        List<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();
        
        list.add(tUser);
            
            
        
        return list;
    }
```

When I am trying a post new user in the localhost with RESTClient (Firefox add-ons) my request body is a json input like that:

```
{"user":{"username":"blabla","fullname":"blabla","gender":"M","birthDate":"05.01.1978"}}
```

In the post method (in the UserService class) must  the variable "tUser" automatically filled with the coming input ? "tUser" variable shows null elements in it in the debugging mode like that:

[image]

If I know wrong could somebody correct me please? Why this values shows null? Must not them shows "blabla" - "blabla" - "M" - "05.01.1878" ? Could you help me please?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem; In the JAXBContextResolver class I change the method like that :

```
public JAXBContextResolver() throws Exception {

        this.context = 
        new JSONJAXBContext(  JSONConfiguration.mapped().rootUnwrapping(false).build(), types); 
}
```

The difference with the first one is adding "rootUnwrapping(false)" expression.

Answer (score 0):

`@XmlRootElement` is not working in your example. Send

```
{"username":"blabla","fullname":"blabla","gender":"M","birthDate":"05.01.1978"}
```

instead
**EDIT**
**1)**

```
public List<User> createNewUser(Request tUser)
```

and class

```
class Request
{
   public User user;
}
```

**2)**

```
public List<User> createNewUser(String tUser)
```

and convert `String` to object using `google-gson` or `jackson json processor`

Comment: But the input must be like that due to our project rules:
`{"user":{"username":"blabla","fullname":"blabla","gender":"M","birthDate":"05.01.1978"}}`

Comment: I tried first method (1) of your edited answer, but while I am trying to send request with post method, the RESTClient gives error like that: 
HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type
description The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.

Comment: @hasan ofcource, you should add annotations to this class. It's only pattern of class

Comment: I am sorry but what do you mean exactly? Could you explain please?